# How can I navigate any directory in Finder?

Tags: macos, finder

The Finder shows several particular directories in the home folder.
It does not even show directory I made in the home folder.

But I do want to navigate any directory of the file system. How can I do that?

Comment: Does the folder name you created starts with a dot?

Comment: @LoïcWolff No. The finder just show these **music**, **photo** etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To access any folder in Finder, press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> and enter the directory you want to access.

Comment: seems works. But it's still different from I see in the shell. When i go to **/**, it just shows several directories and some are renamed to my language.

Comment: @LoïcWolff Don't you mean CMD+SHIFT+G?

Comment: Mac OS use a trick to translate some folder based on your language. Like the ones in your home folder. In `/`, they "flag" some folder to stay invisible.

Answer (score 2):

In Finder there is a shortcut for toggling showing hidden files: `Cmd-Shift-.`

Comment: Just an FWI... This does not work in all versions of OS X/macOS. I just tested it under OS X 10.8.5 and OS X 10.11.6 and it does not work. It did work in macOS 10.12.5.

Answer (score 0):

#### Showing all files in Finder

Type in the terminal

> defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE

Then log out and back in.

Comment: or type in "killall Finder" so you don't have to log out.